# Looking for U2F-Token for TOTP

Tags: security

I am looking for a hardware token to use 2 Factor Authentication which supports TOTP for multiple Services. I want to secure my most important accounts (like E-Mail and everything with payments) with 2FA and I want to setup 2 identical tokens, so one can stay in a safe place as a backup if the main token is lost (USB-A or better USB-C, NFC isn't important).

Basically, I want to be:

1. independent from my smartphone, which could get lost, destroyed, stolen or something like this ( and I had to migrate the security keys to new hardware, which may be a few days away, if i have to buy a new phone and sometimes long ways, to get access to your account, without the old smartphone), so any app like Google Authenticator, Authy, FreeOTP, etc... is no option
2. independent from my laptop: I have a Laptop running Linux with KeePass (which I could use a TOTP-Plugin with), also it would be possible to install the Software, provided by Yubico (https://developers.yubico.com/OATH/YubiKey_OATH_software.html) and use a Yubikey together with this Software, but so i would always need some kind of computer with this software installed.  And in the end the laptop - like a smartphone - could be stolen, broken, etc...
3. independent from Google Services, which also ends in the fact, that i don't want to use the Titan security key (https://cloud.google.com/titan-security-key/)

And so comes the problem:

With the Exception of Yubikey (no TOTP without additional Software) and the Google Titan Key (see Point 3 above), I can't find any hardware token with at least a little bit of a trustful Background (good Press, well known Company behind, ...) which could fulfill what I want.

I found the company Protectimus (https://www.protectimus.com/tokens), but they seem to focus on business users, and the tokens all come with "pre-installed key" (no way).

Also the RSA SecureID focuses on big companies, but isn't a solution for private users.

Is there really no other alternative to those widely supported smartphone apps for private users besides Yubikey and Google Titan?